# gitignore and gitattributes precedence

Tags: git, gitignore, gitattributes

If I get it right, `.gitignore` takes precedence over `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude`, but `$GIT_DIR/info/attributes` takes precedence over `.gitattributes`. Is this by design?

Answer (score 3):

This is documented.

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes

> When deciding what attributes are assigned to a path, Git consults `$GIT_DIR/info/attributes` file (which has the highest precedence), `.gitattributes` file in the same directory as the path in question, and its parent directories up to the toplevel of the work tree (the further the directory that contains `.gitattributes` is from the path in question, the lower its precedence). Finally global and system-wide files are considered (they have the lowest precedence).

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

> the following order of precedence, from highest to lowest (within one level of precedence, the last matching pattern decides the outcome):

> Patterns read from the command line for those commands that support them.

> Patterns read from a `.gitignore` file in the same directory as the path, or in any parent directory, with patterns in the higher level files (up to the toplevel of the work tree) being overridden by those in lower level files down to the directory containing the file. These patterns match relative to the location of the `.gitignore` file. A project normally includes such `.gitignore` files in its repository, containing patterns for files generated as part of the project build.

> Patterns read from `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude`.

> Patterns read from the file specified by the configuration variable `core.excludesFile`.

The order is perhaps because in `.gitignore` you can use negative paths to unignore previously ignored paths. In `.gitattributes` you cannot use negative paths but you can set attributes to different values.

Comment: Normally I believe `$GIT_DIR` should take precedence over dotfiles, since the former is for one dev while the latter for all devs. But in the ignore case, the dotfile can negate a pattern set in `$GIT_DIR`, to my surprise. This means if a dotfile says `!a.txt` then you have no way to ignore it in `$GIT_DIR`.